# Android Phonegap JQM dialog is opening in new page instead of dialog

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. I'm trying to get a dialog box to open using Jquery mobile. I followed the documentation and used the data-rel="dialog" notation along with the data-transition="pop". Instead of a dialog appearing on the same page, I get a brand new page with the dialog appearing. Can someone kindly assist me on how to fix this functionality.

Here is my code for the initial main page:

```
<article>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="star" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="#black_seed_desc" data-rel="dialog"  ><img src="black_seed.jpg"/>
                        <h3>Black Seed Oil</h3>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#black_seed_purchase" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Purchase Black Seed Oil</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
```

Here is my code for the dialog page:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="black_seed_purchase" data-theme="c">
    <section data-role="content">
        <h1>Purchase Black Seed Oil?</h1>
        <p>By purchasing Black Seed Oil you will receive
        an email receipt copy sent to you for your reference.</p>
        <a href="#purchase_blackseed" data-inline="true" data-corners="true" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
        data-wrapperrels="span">
        <span>
            <span>Buy: $49.99</span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-inline="true"       data-corners="true"
        data-wrapperrels="span" data-shadow="true" data-iconshawdow="true">
        <span>
            Cancel
        </span>
        </a>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here is a working example.  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w3ptm/?

Also here is a screen shot of what I'm trying to get.

[image]

Here's what I have:

[image]

Comment: The dialog appears like a page, instead of a dialog?

Comment: Yes. It appears as a page.

Comment: Are you sure all tags are closed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/S3Ddt/ clicking the icon opens the dialog.

Comment: I think it's a bug in androids phonegap jquerymobile framework. It works when I paste my entire code in jfiddle.

Comment: Maybe phonegap/Cordova problem, not sure.

Comment: Yes I agree. I will research to see if there's another resolution if not then I will just create another page as oppose to a dialog. thanks for the help brother.

Answer (score 0):

There is coustome dialog defined by corodova you can use that.

[check this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert)

This might help you.